# Modifications to data members do not persist after function ends

Tags: class, c++11, stdvector

I've got a simple hierarchy which consists of an Agent that has a `ConversationManager con_manager*` data member that handles an arbitrary amount of Conversations in a `std::vector<Conversation> conversations` which themselves contain 1-5 Messages in a `std::Vector<Message> messages` .

If I start a Conversation via

```
ConversationManager::startConversation(Message &message) {
    Conversation conversation = Conversation(message);
    conversations.push_back(conversation)
}
```

The message is saved properly.
But after adding messages via

```
int ConversationManager::addMessage(Message &message){
    if(conversations.size() > 0){
        Conversation conversation = conversations.back();
        conversation.addMessage(message);
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

and

```
int Conversation::addMessage(Message &message){
    …
    messages.push_back(message);
    …
}
```

subsequent messages besides the first one are not saved. Printing the size and content of `messages` in `Conversation::addMessage(Message &message)`shows that my message is saved within that function, but seems to get lost when the scope of the function ends. To my understanding, an explanation would be that the `conversation` objects used in `ConversationManager::addMessage(Message &message)` is merely a copy and thus modifications are not saved. But `std::Vector::back()` returns a reference, so this should be impossible.

I tried only having a single Conversation object without the ConversationManager and then messages are permanently saved. I have a feeling that the Problem lies in my misunderstanding of reference usage. I don't think more code is needed for understanding, but I can provide it if someone thinks it's needed. Any help as to why this occurs would be appreciated, I think I'm making a fundamental mistake here but can't get out of the "This shouldn't be happening"-mindset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
Conversation conversation = conversations.back();
```

creates a copy.
Use

```
Conversation& conversation = conversations.back();
```

to use a reference.

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb. Thanks for the immediate answer

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
if(conversations.size() > 0){
    Conversation conversation = conversations.back();
    conversation.addMessage(message);
    return 0;
}
```

The second line in the snippet above makes a **copy** of a conversation, then adds a message to the copy. Then the recently-modified copy “disappears” when it goes out of scope at the end of the block.

You can create a *reference to* a conversation, then modify the existing conversation, like this:

```
if(conversations.size() > 0){
    Conversation& conversation = conversations.back();  // note reference 
    conversation.addMessage(message);
    return 0;
}
```